# Has anyone experienced Cloudflare 403 Errors with zombie.js web scraping?/

Tags: dns, cloudflare, zombie.js

We're looking to do some scraping on a specific URL that uses cloudflare. Has anyone experienced issues using Zombie.js/user-agents while trying to crawl cloudflare hosted sites.

Would love some help!

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to interface to an API on a client's site and I am getting a 403 error indeed. The request doesn't even reach my server.

Turning security to "essentially off" did not help. The final solution was to white-list the developer machine's IP.

The error is triggered on a single URL (json serving API) with a Java client with standards compliant libraries.

Solution: 
1. try to set a rule to allow direct access for that URL
2. try setting security to weaker and weaker ("essentially off")
3. if both fails: try whitelisting
4. set up an alternate non-cloudflare url (direct.domain.com)

These will of course only work if you can negotiate with the site owners.

Backup solution:  use an embedded browser that you can "frame" and "remote control" or a testing framework that does the same through a plugin, and extract the content from there (if you can)
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably triggering one of our security features by trying to scrape a site on us. The only option, really, would be to ask the site owner to whitelist your IP(s) to override the behavior.